# Using div value like php variable

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I have a script like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showSelected(val){
        document.getElementById
('selectedResult').innerHTML = "The selected number is - " 
+ val;
    }
</script>

<div id='selectedResult'></div>

<select name='test' onChange='showSelected(this.value)'>
    <option value='1'>one</option>
    <option value='2'>two</option>
</select>
```

The output is shown with

```
<div id='selectedResult'></div>
```

So, I want to use this a variable

Actually, I want to get drop down box value with out submit. This script make it, but I can use another suggestions

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I really understand the question, but if you want to get what's stored in the DIV, use:

```
var stuff = document.getElementById('selectedResult').innherHTML;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, so how can I use this variable in php

Comment: You can't. PHP runs when creating the page, Javascript runs after the page has been sent to the browser. If you want to use the variable in PHP, you have to send it back to the server, either by submitting a form or using AJAX.

Comment: Is there any way to do use select box value is a variable for php with out submit?

Comment: You have to either submit the form or use AJAX. PHP doesn't run until the browser sends something to the server. You need to understand the relationship between client-side and server-side scripting in web applications.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you another alternative i think is more useful and you can use it in different    way @ your project.
In this example you click the options you one and insert them to option list, you can send them from your select name=test if you want, you just need to change it.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YuM7a/1/)

This is the script you can catch item,links,images,attributes and add them to select box:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li').on('click',function(){
        $('#theSelect').append('<option   SELECTED>'+$(this).find('img').attr('value')+'</option>');
        var seen = {};
$('option').each(function() {
var txt = $(this).text();
if (seen[txt])
    $(this).remove();
else
    seen[txt] = true;
});
    });

     })

$('#del').click(function() {
var $list = $('#theSelect option');
var d = $list.length;

var b=($list.length-1);
$('#theSelect option:eq('+b+')').remove();

 });
```

Comment: Actually this is not what I want. I explain more, I have submit form include dropdown box and text fields, I need to write selected content of dropdown box to textfield without submit. But I'm writing some different outputs to same field, because of the dropdown box selections has to be a variable.

Comment: Ok, i`m just give you some way to add and remove to/from anywhere, you can implement it on your own.